# How to print variable value using from a domain object value

Tags: java, grails

I have a class **classA** and a variable **newvariable** as

```
class classA
{
string strvarbl="newvariable";
}

String newvariable="Java";

classA aobj=new classA();
println "show:"+aobj.strvarbl
```

is their any possible way to get the value "**Java**" by calling ***aobj.strvarbl***  instead of getting **"newvariable"**

Is their anything like *valueOf(aobj.strvarbl)*,that may print "Java" ..??

Comment: What is the link between strobj and newvariable  ?

Comment: You *could* use a string of a variable name, to find the value that said variable is referring to. But it's quite hackish and not a good solution. I do not see a reason why you'd want to do this in this case.

Any way, how you could do that is using reflection: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldValues.html

(But it's not a neat solution, I think you are looking for a simple solution, which would be to not do it)

Comment: @Bilal BOUTAYA actualy their is no link between the object and variable. The code above is a small interpretation of my actual issue. I need both the object and the variable.

Comment: add the variable to your object.

Comment: it has to be this way

Comment: Yes there is a way in Grails to do that. use println "show: ${aobj.strvarbl}" this would solve your problem to get the JAVA

Comment: @Chetan Hallan  "show: ${aobj.strvarbl}" prints as "show:newvariable"

Comment: Yes right that won't print as expected :|